# How to update the text of a tooltip in JavaFX while the tooltip is shown?

Tags: java, javafx, tooltip

I have a series of elements (`vehicules`) which have a few parameters that I would like to visualize with a tooltip and see how they change. However, I can't find any way to update the tooltip's text while it is being shown.

Currently I am updating the text of the tooltip with the `tooltip.onShowing()` but this doesn't seem to be the correct approach as it doesn't change the text.

Here you have my current code for it with a parameter example that I would like to update (`altitude`):

```
Tooltip tt = new Tooltip(toolTipText);
tt.setOnShowing(event -> {
    tt.setText(toolTipText + "\n" + "Altitude: " + altitude / 1000);
});
```

Furthermore, the `altitude` field has been added to this class (`vehiculeFX`) exclusively to update the tooltip's text and its updated from another class `monitor`, which controls the state of real `vehicules` and their representation on a GUI.

Ideally I would like to have a function that can be called from `monitor` to update the text of the tooltip in `vehiculeFX` without having to add parameters to this class and that would be called every X milliseconds to update the text.

This is the current loop in the `monitor` class that takes the information from `vehicule` and updates `vehiculeFX`:

```
@Override
public void run()
{
    int i;
    while (true)
    {
        float vehiculeData[] = new float[10];
        for (i = 0; i < enjambre.numDrones(); i++)
        {
            Vehicule v = vehicules.get(i)
            vehiculeData = v.getVehiculeData();
            vehiculesFX.get(i).updateAltitude(vehiculeData[5]);
        }
    }
}
```

And I would like to change `vehiculesFX.get(i).updateAltitude(vehiculeData[5]);` with something like `vehiculesFX.get(i).updateTooltip(vehiculeData)` to avoid overloading with fields the `vehiculeFX` class with duplicated information from another class.

Comment: Simply calling `tooltip.setText(...)` will update a tooltip's text. If it is currently showing, the text will be dynamically updated on the screen. If it's not working, something is wrong in other code you have. Create an example from scratch that does nothing except update a tooltip dynamically: get rid of all the extra stuff that has nothing to do with solving that problem. In other words, create a [mre]. (You should already have done this as part of your own troubleshooting efforts before posting here.)

Comment: `Tooltip` has a `Text` property.  Change whatever stores the altitude in whatever `vehiclesFX.get(i)` is to an `IntegerProperty` or `DoubleProperty` have `updateAltitude()` delegate to the `set()` function of that property.  Then bind that property to `tt.textProperty()`.  If your are using JFX19+ you can use `ObservableValue.map()` to build the full text of the Tooltip.